# How is /= translated to actual hardware in vhdl

Tags: comparison, vhdl, synthesis, vivado, hardware

I am a beginner in VHDL/FPGA programming. I want to compare two 32-bit `std_logic_vector`s. I am currently using:

```
      if ( RX_FRAME(to_integer(s_data_counter)).Data /= REF_FRAME(to_integer(s_data_counter)).Data ) then
        s_bad_frame <= '1';
        state <= DONE;
      end if;
```

Here `RX_FRAME` and `REF_FRAME` are 2 arrays of `std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)`

I want to know how the synthesis tool translates `/=` into hardware.
Is it advisable to use this? Or should I do an `XOR` of the concerned vectors and check the resulting vector against zeros? In case I do an `XOR` and check against zeroes, doesn't it increase the amount of hardware needed?
I am using Vivado Design Suite 2015.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Morten already presented, compare operations are implemented in LUTs doing some kind of X(N)OR and AND/(N)OR aggregation.

But it could be faster ...
FPGAs have fast carry chains, which can be used to speed up compare operations with wide inputs, but synthesis tools mostly don't utilize this special resources.

How to do an equality comparation using a carry chain?
Carry chains can be implemented as **k**ill-**p**ropagate chains. This naming comes from ripple carry adders, wherein a carry out can be generated, propagated from carry in or be killed.

A comparator starts with an active carry in (all is equal). Each step computes in the LUT: An = Bn. If yes, propagate the carry bit else kill it.

If the carry out is high (the initial value has survived the chain) all bits were equal.

### Appendix for Morten Zilmer

I don't have an example code for the *equal* or *unequal* operation, but I have a similar example for `prefix and` and `prefix or` operators using carry chains to speed up computation for wide inputs.

- [`prefix_and`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/arith/arith_prefix_and.vhdl) calculates: `y(i) <= '1' when x(i downto 0) = (i downto 0 => '1') else '0';`
  **Explanation:**
  The resulting vector is `1` until the first `0` is found, after that it is `0`.
  Or in other words: The first zero found at position `i` while going from `0 to n` **kills** all remaining bits regardless of the input bits.
- [`prefix_or`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/arith/arith_prefix_or.vhdl) calculates: `y(i) <= '0' when x(i downto 0) = (i downto 0 => '0') else '1';`

  **Explanation:**
  The resulting vector is `0` until the first `1` is found, after that it is `1`.
  Or in other words: The first one found at position `i` while going from `0 to n` **generates** an one and propagates it to all remaining bits regardless of the input bits.

The following code is a generic VHDL description of `prefix_and`. It is vendor independent, but uses special primitives (MUXCY) on Xilinx FPGAs.

```
architecture rtl of arith_prefix_and is
begin
  y(0) <= x(0);
  gen1: if N > 1 generate
    signal  p : unsigned(N-1 downto 1);
  begin
    p(1) <= x(0) and x(1);
    gen2: if N > 2 generate
      p(N-1 downto 2) <= unsigned(x(N-1 downto 2));

      -- Generic Carry Chain through Addition
      genGeneric: if VENDOR /= VENDOR_XILINX generate
        signal  s : std_logic_vector(N downto 1);
      begin
        s <= std_logic_vector(('0' & p) + 1);
        y(N-1 downto 2) <= s(N downto 3) xor ('0' & x(N-1 downto 3));
      end generate genGeneric;

      -- Direct Carry Chain by MUXCY Instantiation
      genXilinx: if VENDOR = VENDOR_XILINX generate
        component MUXCY
          port (
            S  : in  std_logic;
            DI : in  std_logic;
            CI : in  std_logic;
            O  : out std_logic
          );
        end component;
        signal  c : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
      begin
        c(0) <= '1';
        genChain: for i in 1 to N-1 generate
          mux : MUXCY
            port map (
              S  => p(i),
              DI => '0',
              CI => c(i-1),
              O  => c(i)
            );
        end generate genChain;
        y(N-1 downto 2) <= c(N-1 downto 2);
      end generate genXilinx;

    end generate gen2;
    y(1) <= p(1);
  end generate gen1;
end architecture;
```

Source: [`PoC.arith.prefix_and`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/arith/arith_prefix_and.vhdl)

Comment: Can you add a short VHDL code example that is likely to make the synthesis tool map to such a skill-propagate chain; is does it required use of technology specific modules?

Comment: @MortenZilmer added an example. Please [contact](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/AUTHORS.md) me, if you have further questions :).

Comment: Thanks for the example, and I see that a prefix check (longest 0/1) can benefit from carry chain.  But for a chain, the time is linear (`O(n) = n`), where a simple compare can be a tree structure, where time is logarithmic (`O(n) = ln(n)`).  So I don't see a skill-propagate chain as a faster replacement for simple compare.

Comment: That's because carry chains have a very low routing delay compared to normal wires. I'm using `prefix_and` in an LRU list implementation which was much faster after using it. I'll look if I find any measurements.

Comment: Thanks for updating this, and I will remember the trick for timing critical code :-)

Comment: I went through the answer, and understood the working of this module. I still have one doubt though. i.e., 
"The input for these modules must be either 'XNOR'(for 'prefix_and') or 'XOR'(for 'prefix_or') of the 2 wide vectors to be compared. And check the MSB of the output to be HIGH or LOW respectively."
Did I get it right?

Comment: @VinayMadapura Yes, in case of an equal (xnor) operator, you pre-compute `x(i) <= a(i) xnor b(i);` or just `x <= a xnor b;` in VHDL. Then you have compare each bit, but you don't know if the complete `x` vector is filled with ones. So you use prefix_and to check all bit's for ones. If the carry out (MSB) of the prifix_and `y` vector is one, then there was no zero in the vector. While prefix_and is mapped into the carry chain, the xnor operation maps to a LUT. Moreover, because you don't need intermediat carry values, synthesis can map 3 consecutive a and b bits into one LUT6 of an Xilinx FPGA.

Comment: @VinayMadapura So synthesis should compute `y(i/3) <= (a(i+0) xnor b(i+ 0)) and (a(i+1) xnor b(i+1)) and (a(i+2) xnor b(i+2));`, This shortens the carry chain by 3.

Answer (score 7):

You should do compare with `/=` to really benefit from a language like VHDL and advanced synthesis tools like Xilinx Vivado.

The synthesis tool will then implement this using internal LUTs in the FPGA, maybe with a function similar to XOR gates for variable arguments, or AND/NOT gates if one of the arguments evaluates to a constant.  The best way to see the actual implementation is to bring up a GUI view in the tool that shows the implemented design.

But starting to double guess the tool by doing XOR gates yourself is usually a bad idea, since the tool is usually much better to determine the best implementation.  However, if you experience that the tool can't identify a specific construction and select an effective implementation, it may be a good idea to guide the tool with more implementation near coding style, but for a compare like `/=` this is rarely the case.